# Excel change row name [1,2,3] to column name [A, B, C] and vice versa

Tags: excel

For the convenience of editing Excel data, I want to totally transpose the Excel worksheet and make the column name `[1, 2, 3, ...]` and row name `[A, B, C, ...]`.

[image][image]

I know there's an R1C1 reference style to select, but it only makes column name become `[1, 2, 3...]`, and row name remains `[1, 2, 3...]`.

[image]

I was wondering if there are some ways to make the row name become `[A, B, C...]`.

Comment: Wrong site. You're looking for [su] instead. This site is for programming related questions.

Comment: no there isn't. The closest you can get is hiding the headers and using formulas in the first column and row

Comment: Alrighty then, have to use R1C1 style

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change this behavior, follow these steps:

1. Start Microsoft Excel.
2. On the Tools menu, click Options.
3. Click the **General tab**.
4. Under **Settings**, click to clear the **R1C1 reference style**
   check box (upper-left corner), and then click OK.

If you select the **R1C1 reference style** check box, Excel changes the reference style of both row and column headings, and cell references from the A1 style to the R1C1 style.

Comment: Is there any way to make the row headings become `[A, B, C,...]` while column headings are `[1, 2, 3...]`?

Comment: In general, you cannot change the column letters. They are part of the Excel system.

Comment: Great!  Glad to help you. :)